# How to scan elements separated by comma inside a string?

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have a set of strings following this format:

```
{1, 20, 55, 4}
{1}
{90, 2}
```

Inside parenthesis there are numbers separated by comma.
My goal is to extract the **arity** of the given strings, in other words the number of elements inside the given string.
In the first case 4, in the second 1, and 2.
What is the best approach in Java to detect elements separated by comma considering also the parenthesis?

Comment: Show us the code that you tried so far please.

Comment: What parentheses?

Comment: @vandench OP is obviously referring to the `{}` braces, when saying `()` parentheses *(singular: parenthesis)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest approach is to use [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-), e.g. `s.split(",", -1).length`.

Whether that's the "best" approach is debatable.

*Demo*

```
String[] testData = { "{1, 20, 55, 4}", "{1}", "{90, 2}" };
for (String s : testData)
    System.out.println(s.split(",", -1).length);
```

*Output*

```
4
1
2
```

Comment: Only problem is `"{}"` should be length 0.

Comment: @ggorlen Then add `if` statement for that. Or conditional operator: `s.equals("{}") ? 0 : s.split(",", -1).length`